# Telerik skin not working properly

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using telerik rad controls on my asp net webforms application. And now I am having a problem with the skins, it works only on specific pages.

This is the thing...I have two pages `PlacementProvider.aspx and ProviderDetails.aspx`.

On the first page(`PlacementProvider.aspx`) everything is working. I can apply any of the skins as i want using the smart tag on `RadGrid` but on the second page(`ProviderDetails.aspx`) I only get the default skin when trying to choose a skin to `RadGrid` using the smart tag.

On the other side if I copy and paste the first page(`PlacementProvider.aspx`) and try the same thing it works.

Now, what is the the difference between this pages, how can I get the skin working on all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any design time errors in the ProviderDetails.aspx when you switch to Design mode?

If the smart tag does not offer the rest of the available skins, you can type them manually as a value of the Skin property.

The available skins are enlisted at https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/controlling-visual-appearance/how-skins-work#built-in-skins, e.g.

Black

BlackMetroTouch

Bootstrap

Default

Glow

Material (available for the Lightweight RenderMode only)

Metro

MetroTouch

Office2007

Office2010Black

Office2010Blue

Office2010Silver

Outlook

Silk

Simple

Sunset

Telerik

Vista

Web20

WebBlue

Windows7